# Is possible to change friend list privacy programmatically?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I'm building a Facebook app, but I need to access user friend list. Even when usr has set it as not visible.
Is possible to change it via code?

Comment: Do you mean just their friends in general, or the lists they might have specifically created? Anyway, both is available to your app if it asks for the right permissions. If something is private or not does not matter, as long as the user gives you the right permissions.

Comment: hi, I mean just friends in general. Some user set it like you only can see mutual friends. Do you mean once he gives permission to access friends list I can see all of them anyway?  On graph I've been doing some test but it returns me only mutal friends

Comment: Yes, with appropriate permission it returns all of the user’s friends. (Minus those who have disabled apps in general.)